# How to display true or false as JSON result | PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Currently it is formatted like:

```
[{"person":"Jake"}]


$stmt = $pdo->prepare(

'SELECT `person`,
       sum( `type` = "Broken" ) as `typeNumber`
            FROM `Table1`
            WHERE (`name` = :name
            AND
            (`job` = "collection")
            group by `person` ');

      $stmt->execute([
          'name' => $_POST['name']
          ]);

      $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      echo json_encode($row);
```

If 1 or more records are selected I would like {true} to appear otherwise {false} should be the default.

No square brackets need to surround either

Comment: The parentheses aren't balanced in the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `EXISTS` query.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM Table1
        WHERE name = :name AND job = 'collection'
    ) AS found");
$stmt->execute(['name' => $_POST['name']]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($row['found'] == 1);
```

MySQL encodes `TRUE` as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`, the comparison will convert this to JSON `true/false`.

If you just care whether any rows are matched, there's no need to group the results or sum anything.